# How will the charges redistribute among the 2 charged balls with different materials and different radius when they are touched?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, equilibrium

How will the charges redistribute among the 2 charged balls **with different materials**, **different radius** when they are touched?

If the 2 balls have the same material, then we have:
$$q_1 + q_2 = q'_1 + q'_2 (1)$$
$$\frac{k q'_1}{\epsilon r_1} = \frac{k q'_2}{\epsilon r_2}$$
$$ => \frac{q'_1}{r_1} = \frac{q'_2}{r_2} (2)$$

$\epsilon$: relative permittivity

k = $9.10^9$

But what if these balls have different materials?

Comment: Like a conductor and an insulator?

Comment: @JonCuster I mean, for example, let a charged aluminum ball contact with a charged iron ball. How will the charges redistribute among these balls? Does it still like when 2 charged balls with the same material touched?

Comment: Where in the derivation or explanation of your equations does the material properties come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that your first equation holds. Obviously, charge will be conserved. However, the second equation is specific to conductors. To see this, we look at how the electrons behave. Note that I will use purely classical mechanics. Using Newton's 2nd Law, one can find the equation of motion to be

$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = - e\nabla V$

where $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is the acceleration of an electron and $\nabla V$ is the change in electrostatic potential energy. Note that if the electrostatic potential is constant no electron moves. Therefore, when two charged objects touch, the charge flow stops when the electrostatic potential is uniform.

This principle is very general and can be used to derive your 2nd equation. To see this note that for a metal all the charged particles, since they can move freely, will be distributed on the surface. For a spherical ball, the potential is then given by

$V_1 = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0r_1}$

and similarly for the second ball. We want those potential to be equal so that charge doesn't flow from one place to the other. This condition reduces to your equation.

However, for insulators, it is quite different as in this case the charges are not free to move. Therefore, you cannot say they will be distributed on the surface. However, same principle does still apply (you have to calculate the electrostatic potential in both objects). Now you need to know how the charge is distributed to be able to answer this question.

Comment: So if i let a charged aluminum ball contact with a charged iron ball, can I still can use the second equation?

Comment: Yes you can but it make sure to modify the permittivity of free space.